# How to add custom jar files into pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I am creating a maven project, in which I've two jar's for say x and y  for now,which contains some helper classes for my project. I want to added these  x and y jars to my project's pom.xml as dependency. As these two jar files are not available in maven repository. So I try to use these jar in my pom.xml with in repository tag.How to achieve this. I've searched in google and found one project , which is similar to my project.

when I build this it able to build application, I saw the jar file it created.But I couldn't create the same with new project. If I copy the entire pom.xml I'm able to build.What is dependency-reduced-pox.xml and how it will create. and in moven-local folder how it creates another pom.xml, which command is used to create these auto generated xml files Can any one help me to do this. Here are the screen shots of my maven project I got it .
[image]
here are other screen shot.[image]

Comment: are those two x and y jars also maven projects?

Comment: no, those are simple java projects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add local jar files to a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways:

A) Install your JARs to your local Maven repository and then use them in your project with provided groupId, artifactId and version: [How to add local jar files to a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project) (this is quick & easy & pretty clean until you remove your local repository and delete your JARs accidentally).

B) Install Nexus or Artifactory (will will be then your remote Maven repository), set it up in your settings.xml, add those JARs to remove Maven repository and download them from there (this is much less error-prone, but in longer run it's worth it).

C) not recommended: Other response (btw. currently with most upvotes) from previously suggested resource: [How to add local jar files to a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project) which contains systemPath tag. You shouldn't use it, because it will cause lots of headaches in the future (for example if you want to package your application to WAR), it's not the correct way, but it's possible.